# Get tags from Prometheus (with alertManager)

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

sI have a PromQL request for checking prometheus values:

```
sum by(channel)(increase(preference_process_invalid_json_count_total{service=~"nfs-bundle-processor.*"}[5m]))
```

The prometheus metric can have several "channel" tag values:

[image]

I need to get alle the channels into the `$labels.channel` to the message:

```
'{{ $labels.service | toUpper }} - [{{ $value }}] invalid preferenceProcess kafka jsons by channels "{{ $labels.channel }}"'
```

How is it possible if it is?
If it's not - is it possible to get 1 alert message from every channel?

Comment: The configuration that you provide looks ok to me. You need to setup the alert using your query and alert manager will create one alert per channel. Isn't it working?